# Admin bar is showing up to non logged in users

Tags: theme-development

Even after logout from wordpress admin, Admin bar is still showing up on front-end.

Attaching screenshot here,
[image]

When I change theme, Admin bar doesn't showing up. It looks like there is issue only with this theme. Its custom theme that I am working.

`functions.php`

```
<?php 
/*

File Name: functions.php

*/

if( ! function_exists( 'triangle_setup ' ) ) : 

function triangle_setup(){

 show_admin_bar( true );
   add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
   add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'comment-list', 'comment-form', 'search-form', 'gallery', 'caption' ) );

   add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
   set_post_thumbnail_size( 850, 400, true );

   add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'gallery','audio', 'audio','chat' ));

   add_theme_support( 'menus' );

   register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'triangle' ),
    'social'  => __( 'Social Links Menu', 'triangle' ),
) );


}

endif;
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'triangle_setup');

/**
 * Registering scripts and styles
 */


 function trianagle_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'tr-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'tr-fontawsome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'tr-lighbox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/lightbox.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'tr-prettyphoto', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/prettyPhoto.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'tr-responsive', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/responsive.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('tr-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );



    //wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'tr-jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tr-bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tr-masonary', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/masonry.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tr-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tr-audio', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/audio.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tr-countdowntimer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/coundown-timer.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tr-gmaps', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/gmaps.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tr-holder', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/holder.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tr-html5shiv', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/html5shiv.js');

    wp_script_add_data( 'tr-html5shiv', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'tr-count', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.countTo.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tr-fitvids', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.fitvids.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tr-isotope', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.isotope.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tr-lightbox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lightbox.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tr-respond', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/respond.min.js');

    wp_script_add_data( 'tr-respond', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'tr-wow', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/wow.min.js');


    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'trianagle_scripts' );

/* 
    Registering Google Fonts
*/

function google_fonts() {
    $query_args = array(
        'family' => 'Open+Sans:400,700|Oswald:700|Lato:100,300,400,700|Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,400,300,600,700|Noto+Sans:400,700'
    );
    wp_register_style( 'google_fonts', add_query_arg( $query_args, "//fonts.googleapis.com/css" ), array(), null );
 }

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'google_fonts');


/* 
    Navigation Walker Class<br>
*/


class tr_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ) {
        $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];

        if ( is_object( $args[0] ) ) {
            $args[0]->has_children = !empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
        }


        if (!empty($children_elements[$element->$id_field]) && $element->menu_item_parent == 0) { 
            $element->title =  $element->title . '<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>'; 
        }

        if (!empty($children_elements[$element->$id_field]) && $element->menu_item_parent != 0) { 
            $element->title =  $element->title . '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'; 
        }

        return parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
    }


   function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0,$args = Array()) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu \" role=\"menu\">\n";
    }



   function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth =0  , $args = Array() ,$id = 0 ) {
        if ( $args->has_children ) {
            $item->classes[] = 'dropdown';

        }

        parent::start_el($output, $item, $depth , $args ,$id = 0);
    }
}

/* Customizer for Triangle theme */

function triangle_customizer($wp_customize){

    $wp_customize -> add_section( 'triangle_logo_section' , array(
    'title'       => __( 'Logo', 'triangle' ),
    'priority'    => 30,
    'description' => 'Upload a logo to replace the default site name and description in the header',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'triangle_logo' );

    $wp_customize -> add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'triangle_logo', array(
    'label'    => __( 'Logo', 'triangle' ),
    'section'  => 'triangle_logo_section',
    'settings' => 'triangle_logo',
 ) ) );

}
add_action('customize_register', 'triangle_customizer');


function triangle_init(){
    register_sidebar(array(
            'name'=>__('Right Sidebar', 'triangle'),
            'id' => 'sidebar-right',
            'description' => __('Add widgets to right sidebar','triangle'),
            'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title' => '</h2>',
            'before_widget' => '<div  id="%1$s"  class="widget %2$s sidebar-item"  >',
            'after_widget' => '</div>'
    ));
}
add_action('widgets_init','triangle_init');

/**
 * Custom template tags for this theme.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php';
```

`header.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till 
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Triangle
 * @since Triangle 
 */

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>Home | Triangle</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/ico/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
</head>
<!--/head-->

<body  <?php body_class(); ?> >
<header id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 overflow">
        <div class="social-icons pull-right">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
        <?php  if(!empty(get_theme_mod('triangle_logo'))) :?>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url( '/')); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name','display'));?>">
        <h1><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod('triangle_logo')); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo('name','display')); ?>"></h1>
        </a>

        <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
      <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) : ?>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <?php

                     wp_nav_menu(array(
                     'theme_location' => 'primary',
                     'walker' => new tr_Walker_Nav_Menu,
                     'container' => '',
                     'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',  
                     ));

                     ?>

      </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <div class="search">
        <form role="form">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
          <div class="field-toggle">
            <input type="text" class="search-form" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<!--/#header-->
```

Comment: We need to see codes to understand what has happened.

Comment: @RRikesh Is it functions.php or header.php ?

Comment: whatever you added to `functions.php` or anywhere that could have triggered that issue.

Comment: @RRikesh I've updated question

Comment: I had this problem only once when using a caching plugin that obviously even saves the admin bar when a page is first being viewed by someone logged in. Could that be the case here?

Comment: @physalis I haven't installed any plugin. Its fresh installation of WP

Answer (score 3):

Actually in functions.php, I have removed below line.

```
show_admin_bar( true );
```

And then Go to Dashboard > Users > Your Profile and mark it on "Show Toolbar when viewing site"

Comment: Btw, when you use this code, the Dashboard setting is not taken into consideration https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/show_admin_bar